# Unable to get dotenv module to work with uvicorn

Tags: python, virtualenv, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to run a FastAPI app with uvicorn but I cannot get uvicorn to find the module. Here are some details

**Setup**

. -> **env** (This folder is the virtual env)

|

| -> **backend** (This folder has the FastAPI app)

This is how the structure looks like

```
.backend
├── __init__.py
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── config.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

I am running Uvicorn from the parent of backend folder with this command

```
uvicorn backend.main:app --reload
```

Further, I have a `config.py` which is inside the `core` folder.

This file is trying to use `dotenv` which is installed inside the virtualenv

config.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

env_path = Path(".") / ".env"
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)


class Settings:
    PROJECT_TITLE: str = "Job Board"
    PROJECT_VERSION: str = "0.1.0"
    POSTGRES_USER: str = os.getenv("POSTGRES_USER")
   ...
```

Here is how main.py uses this file

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from backend.core.config import settings

app = FastAPI(
    title=settings.PROJECT_TITLE,
    version=settings.PROJECT_VERSION,
)


@app.get("/")
def hello_api():
    return {"detail": "Hello World!"}
```

However, I get this error when I run it

```
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/Users/amit/Desktop/fastapi']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [85738] using statreload
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 68, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 448, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/bhallaamit/Desktop/fastapi/./backend/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from backend.core.config import settings
  File "/Users/bhallaamit/Desktop/fastapi/./backend/core/config.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'
```

**Can someone please help me? dotenv is installed in the virtual env.**

Comment: Since you install the dotenv package in the virtual env. , did you call `uvicorn` with the virtualenv activated? However, from your logs, it seems your did not run your application with activated virtualenv.

Comment: That was the problem. I should have done python -m uvicorn instead of running it directly. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I didn't run `uvicorn` from virtualenv. The solution is `python -m uvicorn backend.main:app --reload` instead of directly running it.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.